# Find all integer solutions of the system: $35x+63y+45z=1,|x|<9,|y|<5,|z|<7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**My attempt:**

Taking this equation$\mod 9$, we have
$35x\equiv -x\equiv 1\pmod 9$. Since $|x|<9$,  $x$ can be $-1,8$

Taking this equation$\mod 5$, we have
$63y\equiv 3x\equiv 1\pmod5$. Since $|y|<5$, $y$ can be $2,-3$.

Taking this equation$\mod 7$, we have
$45z\equiv 3z\equiv 1\pmod7$. Since $|z|<7$, $z$ can be $-2,5$.

Substituting these values in the equation, we get two solution for the equation:

$(x,y,z)=(-1,2,-2)$ and $(8,3,-2)$.

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$7(5x+9y)+45z=1=91-90$$

$$\iff7(5x+9y-13)=-45(z+2)\iff\dfrac{45(z+2)}7=13-9y-5x$$ which is an integer

$\implies7\mid45(z+2)\iff7\mid(z+2)\implies z=7m-2$ where $m$ is any integer

$|z|<7\iff-7<z<7\implies-7<7m-2<7\implies0\le m\le1$

If $m=0,z=-2,5x+9y-13=0\iff5x+9y=18-5\iff5(x+1)=9(2-y)$ and so on

If $m=1,z=?; 5x+9y-13=-45$

Can you take it from here?